# How do I use flask Migrate and SQLAlchemy on my own database, and connect to a third party database that I do not wish to migrate?

Tags: python-3.x, orm, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I have discovered a way to connect to multiple databases with Flask through [binds](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/binds.html#creating-and-dropping-tables).

Facts leading up to question:

1. I have defined my own database Models with SQLAlchemy.
2. I use Flask-Migrate to generate my database
3. I wish to connect to a third party database and use the [SQLAlchemy ORM](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html).
4. I wish to query the third party database using the SQLAlchemy ORM in a way such as: `db.session.query(THIRDPARTYMODEL).filter_by(id=id)`
5. I'm worried, that once I define the new models and use Flask Migrate, that it will try to create a new migration and create the tables I already have.
6. I wish to use my own database and the third party database at the same time.

How can I connect to the third party database and query it using the SQLAchemy ORM without worrying about Flask Migrate trying to generate new tables on the third party database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask-Migrate does not automatically migrate multiple databases, the default is to only migrate the main database from Flask-SQLAlchemy.

The problem is that if you have additional models created that belong to another database, Alembic will consider them part of that main database, so it will write migrations for your main database that include the entire set of models.

To have things working the way you want, you will need to ensure those other models that do not belong in the main database are not imported when you invoke the `manage.py db ...` set of commands.

You may also tell Flask-Migrate and Alembic to support migrating multiple databases by using [`flask db init --multidb`](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#multiple-database-support) when initializing the migrations.

Comment: Thank you @miguel yesterday I was able to solve this by editing the env.py file, and use an"include_object" function and pass its value to context.configure(include_object) https://gist.github.com/fogonthedowns/eac20f93b28b61cac71d This feels a little hacky because env.py was generated and my migrations folders is not tracked in my source control. (using .gitignore)

Comment: This is an acceptable solution in my view, but you have to include your migration files in source control. If you ever lose those files you will have no way to recreate the history of your database.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but I wasn't able to use the accepted `include_object` solution because that method is called too far into the migration on the non-migrated database. In my case, the user doesn't have write access, so the migration failed as soon as Alembic tried to make the `alembic_version` table on the remote DB. This happened before `include_object` was called on any of the tables.

Instead, because I wanted Alembic to completely ignore this database and all its tables, I simply put the read-only database in `SQLALCHEMY_BINDS` and then removed it in `migrations/env.py` before it was processed:

```
# ===Generated code===
bind_names = []
for name, url in current_app.config.get("SQLALCHEMY_BINDS").items():
    context.config.set_section_option(name, "sqlalchemy.url", url.replace(
        '%', '%%'))
    bind_names.append(name)

# ===New code===
### Remove the 'remote' bind, which is a read-only database that we don't
### want to track migration changes on.
if 'remote' in bind_names:
    bind_names.remove('remote')
```